# TensorFlow: using tf$summary in TensorFlow Mechanics 101 tutorial

Tags: r, tensorflow

I have successfully tried [TensorFlow Mechanics 101](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorial_tensorflow_mechanics.html) tutorial, and have the following question.

I have found the discrepancy between the values of loss that are output on the console, and those shown by TensorBoard.

My understanding that these should be identical:

- The console output is created on each 100th step by line 190 of `fully_connected_feed.R` and it outputs `loss_value` created on line 182 by `sess$run` applied to the loss operation; thus, it should be the loss for that particular step, rounded to two decimal places.
- The value shown by TensorBoard, applies also to each 100th step.  It appears to be created by lines 194-195 from `summary_str` created on line 193 by applying `sess$run` to the summary operation defined on line 147 as `tf$summary$merge_all()`.  This should pick up the only summary operation, the same loss, which is defined on line 125 of `mnist.R`, and this operation applies to the same step.

Thus, these two values of loss should be identical up to rounding.

However, they are not, although they are close.  I tried comparing them on different data for which learning does not converge that well, and found much larger discrepancies.

It appears to me that I do not understand something basic about TensorFlow summaries.

I am using RStudio Version 1.0.153, R version 3.4.1, all R packages reinstalled today, on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the lines 183-184 of the file [`fully_connected_feed.R`](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/blob/master/inst/examples/mnist/fully_connected_feed.R) of this tuturial:

```
values <- sess$run(list(train_op, loss), feed_dict = feed_dict)
loss_value <- values[[2]]
```

I replaced these two lines by the following code:

```
sess$run(train_op, feed_dict = feed_dict)
loss_value = sess$run(loss, feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

This code appears to be equivalent to original code (and this is what I claimed in an earlier version of this answer, with a reference to [the manual for `tf$Session$run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run)) but [it is not](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13133).

With this code, the problem disappeared and the console output and the summary recording of the result of the same `loss` operation became identical.